# Using Ajax and Jquery to modify Css values, based on a Mysql row

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I have been working on this system to automatically update a Scene Selection page when you get a new number in your permission table on Mysql.
I have the Php for the Login, and the Php for grabbing the number in the permission row of the members table working fine.

My Problem lies with the Jquery (Which I started using yesterday :p) I have added an Jquery Ajax connection at the beginning of the script that connects to this php document:

**connect.php :**

```
<?php
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    //Select Database
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
    // Retrieve data from Query String


//this selects everything for the current user, ready to be used in the script below

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['Username']."' LIMIT 1");

//this function will take the above query and create an array


 //with the array created above, I can create variables (left) with the outputted array (right)
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { var_dump($row); $permission = $row['permission']; }



        echo '<u><b>Permision ID:</b></u> - - No:' .$permission  ; 
?>
```

That works fine, I go to that park after I have logged in and it recalls all the data perfectly.
I believe that the problem lies in the JQuery.

**index.php - JQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

 $.ajax({
   url:'connect.php',
   datatype:"application/json",
   type:'get',
   data: 'q='+permission, 
   success:function(data){
      count('#result').append(html); 
   },
   error:function(){
      // code for error
   }
 });



        if (['permission'] = '1') {
            $('#middle').load(function() {
      $('#Scene1').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete
      });
    });

    }
    //2,3,4,5,6 ommited

    });

    }

        if (['permission'] = '7') {
            $('#middle').load(function() {
      $('#Scene7').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete
      });
    });

    }

//-->
</script>
```

That script should set the display style to inherit so that you can see it when the number in the database is the same as the number of the Scene.

Just to give you some background, here is my Scene.

**#Scene1 :**

```
    <div id="middle">





        <ul id="Scene1" style="display:none;">

<h2 id="unlocked">Act One</h2>
            <li id="navi3"><a href="#"><img src="Images/Scene-one-unlocked-unpressed.png" alt="Scene One completed" height="255px" width="340px"/></li></a>
    <img id="arrow"
    src="Images/Right-Arrow.png" 
    height="80px"
    width="120px"/>
            <li id="navilockedr"><img src="Images/Scene-two-locked.png" alt="Scene Two locked" height="255px" width="340px"/></li>
    <img id="banner"
    src="Images/crime-scene-banner.png" 
    height="5px"
    width="900px"/>
<h2 id="locked">Act Two</h2>
            <li id="navilockedl"><img src="Images/Scene-three-locked.png" alt="Scene three locked" height="255px" width="340px"/></li>
    <img id="arrow"
    src="Images/Right-Arrow.png" 
    height="80px"
    width="120px"/>
            <li id="navilockedr"><img src="Images/Scene-four-locked.png" alt="Scene four locked" height="255px" width="340px"/></li>
    <img id="banner"
    src="Images/crime-scene-banner.png" 
    height="5px"
    width="900px"/>
<h2 id="locked">Act Three</h2>
            <li id="navilockedl"><img src="Images/Scene-five-locked.png" alt="Scene five locked" height="255px" width="340px"/></li>
    <img id="arrow"
    src="Images/Right-Arrow.png" 
    height="80px"
    width="120px"/>
            <li id="navilockedr"><img src="Images/Scene-six-locked.png" alt="Scene six locked" height="255px" width="340px"/></li>

        </ul>
```

I was wondering if anyone skilled in JQuery could point me in the right direction, as I don't know if my syntax is right, or if im simply failing to connect to 'connect.php'.

Comment: Are you sure you're not connecting?  What does your console say?  Are you getting any errors in your console?  If not is anything returned?

Comment: From what see at a glance, your `permission` variable in your ajax call is undefined.

Comment: Also I don't believe `count('#result').append(html);` is correct (for jQuery).  If you're trying to append data to `#result`, you should be using `$('#result').append(html);`

Comment: I am not entirely sure, the only code I'm positive is working fine is the php and the normal html, after checking the console, the only two errors I have are;  
Error:Permission denied to access property 'toString'
and
ReferenceError:invalid assignment left-hand side
if (['permission'] = '1')

Answer (score 0):

```
// This part makes no sense. What you are doing is creating an array with 
// one entry 'permission', then assigning that new array the value of 7. 
if (['permission'] = '7') 
{ 
    // This will always run because non-zero numbers are 'true'
}

// To illustrate this in a more verbose way...

// Create an array with one item, a string 'permission'
var x = new Array();
x.push( 'permission' );

// X is no longer an array, it is now a number
x = 7; 

if ( x ) 
{ 
    // This will always run because non-zero numbers are 'true'
}
```

Aside from this, you'll want to move your display logic up to the ajax callback, or wrap it in a function which is called by the success callback.

Comment: Sorry, its my first time using JavaScript, I thought that ['example'] was the correct format for pulling something from the database.

Comment: What I am trying to do is:
if (the number inside permission) = 1 then show scene 1, I just don't know the syntax for that or how to link permission once I have gotten it from connect.php

Comment: if (<?php echo $permission?> == '1') {
      $('#middle').load(function() {
      $('#Scene1').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete
      });
    });

 } 


Would this work? Thanks for Reading